# Position of array elements

Tags: c++, arrays

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int a, count = 0;
    cin >> a;
    int x[a], y[a], istix[a], istiy[a], br1 = 0, br2 = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < a; i++)
        cin >> x[i] >> y[i];

    for (int i = 0; i < a; i++){
        for (int j = 0; j < a; j++){
            if(x[i] == y[j]){
                count++;
                istix[br1] = i;
                istiy[br2] = j;
                br1++;
                br2++;
            }
        }
    }

    if (count >= 3){
        cout << "Pozicii na isti elementi vo prvata niza:" << endl;
        for (int i = 0; i < br1; i++)
            cout << istix[i] << endl;
        cout << "Pozicii na isti elementi vo vtorata niza:" << endl;
        for (int i = 0; i < br2; i++)
            cout << istiy[i] << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I'm writing a task where I have to check if there are more than 3 elements in the two arrays with same value, if so, I have to output their index in both arrays.

My program outputs correctly for the first array, but not for the second one. I've used the same method for both, so why doesn't it work?

```
5
9 4
2 5
4 1
5 9
12 59
Pozicii na isti elementi vo prvata niza:
0
2
3
Pozicii na isti elementi vo vtorata niza:
3
0
1
```

This is the actual output, everything is correct except the last array :

```
3
0
1
```

It's supposed to be:

```
0
1
3
```

Comment: What is the input, the expected output, and the actual output?

Comment: Updated with expected / actual result.

Comment: The output looks correct to me... Why do you think it should be different?

Comment: The order is not sorted, while it is in the first one.

Comment: Then sort it. But if it was sorted then it wouldn't match the elements in the first array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
int a, count = 0;
cin >> a;
int x[a], y[a], istix[a], istiy[a] ...; // WRONG!
```

This is not valid C++ code.  You cannot declare an array of an unknown size - it must be a constant expression.

If you need a dynamic array, you need to use `new` (and a corresponding `delete`) or use the proper containers (e.g. `std::vector`) that do the job for you.

```
int a;
cin >> a;
int* x = new int[a]; // this will create a dynamic array with a elements
...
delete [] x;
```

Or

```
int a;
cin >> a;
std::vector<int> vec(a);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for this. I'll be sure to use pointers next time, although I don't completely understand your line of code, but I'll try to research and see what it exactly does. As for vectors, I haven't studied them yet.

Comment: @user3002211 "I'll be sure to use pointers next time" - ***NO NO NO NO NO NO*** forget them. In C++, use `vector`.

Comment: @user3002211 Unless this is for an academic exercise, you should use the standard containers (e.g. `vector`).  I only showed the manual memory allocation as it seems this is an academic project.